# python: sentinel-controlled area computation using the coordinate method

Tags: python

A neophyte here. I am trying to create a code that can compute the area of a simple polygon that is sentinel controlled: user inputs the coordinates of the corners, then the area will be computed once the user inputs "STOP", given the he/she had given at least 3 coordinates; otherwise, an error message will appear prompting him to enter another pair of x-and y- coordinates until he gives at least 3 pairs.

When I try to run the program, I always get this error message:
There is an error in your program: invalid syntax

Then the variable v gets highlighted in red.

Btw, here's my code:

```
ans = "" 
sigma2 = 0.0
corner_counter = 1

u1 = float(input("\nx-coordinate of the first corner: "))
v1 = float(input("y-coordinate of the first corner: "))

pu = u1
pv = v1

print "Number of points given: ",corner_counter # just to check the number corners given

while ans != "STOP":

        ans = raw_input("Enter x-coordinate of the next corner or type 'STOP' to compute the area: ")

        if ans == "STOP":
                if corner_counter >= 3:
                    break

                else:
                    u = float(input("ERROR: Must enter at least three (3) corners to compute the area./nEnter x-coordinate of the next corner: ")
                    v = float(input("Enter y-coordinate: "))
                    sigma2 += ((pu * v) - (pv * u))
                    print "(%d * %d) - (%d * %d) =" %(pu, v, pv, u), (pu * v) - (pv * u)
                    print "Partial sum:", sigma2 # to check if the running sum agrees with the expected result
                    corner_counter += 1
                    continue
        else:
           u = float(ans)
           v = float(input("Enter y-coordinate: "))

                sigma2 += ((pu * v) - (pv * u))

                print "(%d * %d) - (%d * %d) =" %(pu, v, pv, u), (pu * v) - (pv * u)
                print "Partial sum:", sigma2 # to check if the running sum agrees with the expected result
                corner_counter += 1
                print "Number of points given: ", corner_counter # for checking purposes

        pu = u
        pv = v

print "(%d * %d) - (%d * %d) =" %(pu, v1, pv, u1), (pu * v1) - (pv * u1)
sigma2 += (u * v1) - (v * u1)
print "\nTOTAL SUM:", sigma2

# final output
print "\nThe area of the", corner_counter,"-sided polygon is", (abs(sigma2)/2), "square unit(s)."
```

I had already tried to change it but nothing seem to work.

Hope you will help me guys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, either in your original code or here. Check that the code is correctly indented and then copy/paste it here if that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: When you're fixing indentation, consider to using 4 spaces, [as recommended by PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).